# why is DOM tree oder preorder, depth-first traversal?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, graph-algorithm

why is DOM tree oder `preorder`, `depth-first traversal`?

What are the advantages of this design choice compared to other traversal like BFT?

I was just looking into [DOM standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-tree-order) and found the definition of preceding and following :

> An object A is preceding an object B if A and B are in the same tree
>   and A comes before B in tree order.
>
> An object A is following an object B if A and B are in the same tree
>   and A comes after B in tree order.
>
> Just like most programming paradigms the Web platform has finite
>   hierarchical tree structures, simply named trees. The tree order is
>   preorder, depth-first traversal.

Comment: This might do better over on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depth-first traversal is generally the easiest traversal style, since you can do it recursively or with an explicit stack; breadth-first requires a queue which is, in some sense, a more complicated data-structure. But I think there is a simpler answer than tradition or simplicity: depth-search traversal of an (X)HTML tree results in the text nodes being traversed in presentation order.

Consider this *relatively* simple [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) subtree.

Or, in HTML:

```html
<p>Consider this <em>relatively</em> simple <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML">HTML</a> subtree</p>
```

As a tree (leaving out whitespace and attributes):

```
                        <P>
                         |
      +----------+-------+-----+------+               
______|______  __|__  ___|__  _|_  ___|___
Consider this   <EM>  simple  <A>  subtree
                 |             |
             ____|_____      __|__
             relatively       HTML
```

Depth-first traverse:

```html
<P>, Consider this, <EM>, relatively, simple, <A>, HTML, subtree
```

Breadth-first traverse:

```html
<P>, Consider this, <EM>, simple, <A>, subtree, relatively, HTML
```

Comment: @user3840170: Here's how your box-drawing characters render on my current Android: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oqwf.jpg. Apparently, in the almost ten years since I wrote this answer, Android rendering of box-drawing characters still hasn't been fixed. I reverted the edit (and changed EMPH to EM).

Comment: Is It posible to do a dom diff algorithm with DFS? Or there is any reasons React did it with BFS? I'm trying to do it in DFS to worlk directly with HTML streaming, but I have some troubles... Do you think is it posible?

Answer (score 2):

A depth-first search requires memory on the order of the tree's height, but a breadth-first search requires memory on the order of the cardinality of the tree's vertices.  In other words, breadth-first search is a memory hog compared to depth-first search.